# WCF REST web service - Deserialization of Json

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, deserialization

I am encountering a problem on my WCF web service.
I have this error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request.

I think is due to the deserialization of the JSON, I will past my code, please give me some help, thank you.

Here is the raw JSON:

```
{
"properties" : {
    "callID" : "4A79825AE0914B6B9B27F477CAF8A32B",
    "timestamp" : "2018-06-05T08:50:41.064+0000",
    "data" : {
      "Name" : "Y",
      "Surname" : "X",
      "Age" : [ "25" ]
    },
    "localEvent" : "X",
    "eventtype" : "X"
   }                                                                            
}
```

And i have the following classes:

```
public class CSModel
{
    public CSProperties properties { get; set; }
}

public class CSProperties
{
    public string callID{ get; set; }
    public string timestamp{ get; set; }
    public CSData DataModel { get; set; }
    public string localEvent{ get; set; }
    public string eventtype{ get; set; }
}
    public class CSData
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }
}
```

And here i decode my JSON:

```
string jsonBody = new StreamReader(contents).ReadToEnd();
CSModel jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CSModel>(jsonBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things which you need to change, since your C# class representation isn't correct

1. Use attributes (`[JsonProperty(ProperyName = "data")]`) to decorate class properties which have different name than the name in the JSON itself. If you don't do that, your `DataModel` property will remain null.
2. `"Age"` property holds value of string array type, which means you need to change C# property into `string[]`. This must be changed to prevent exceptions due to type mismatch